# Interpreting the code "newcolumntype"

Tags: tables, columns

`\newcolumntype{Q}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}`

what does `[1]` and `p{#1}` mean ?

Answer (score 7):

`p` is a standard latex array column specifier

```
\begin{tabular}{cp{3cm}}
```

means that each cell in the second column is a parbox of width 3cm

`Q` here is defined as a new column type taking an argument `Q{...}` where `#1` denotes the argument. so `Q{3cm}` expands to `>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{3cm}`  which is a `p` column with `\centering` applied to each cell.

See the `array` package manual (`texdoc array`) for more details.